# SqLite in Android. Everything was working but suddenly an error arose

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 30, col 9 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Here is my code.

```
Cursor cursor = dataBase.query("MyBooks", null, null, null, null, null, "COLUMN_LAST_OPEN");
cursor.moveToFirst();
if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    do {
        path = cursor.getString(9); //exception arises here

    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Exception arises on the cursor Position 122 although exception says that row is 30. If I'd change the code to iterate from the end to start by calling cursor.moveToPrevious then it's working.

Comment: Are there 10 columns in the result set?  Is your database connection working? (not my downvote)

Comment: There is 12 columns, 124 rows. All rows scan perfect, but row 122 scans only if accessed using moveToPrevious

Comment: I've made a backup of my database file, and after deleting that row program works. But i want to understand what could cause such error.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with stale data, but I don't know Android well enough to give you a formal answer.

Comment: What did the row that you deleted look like?

Comment: 0: some blob data;      1:STRING "The Master Mind of Mars";       2:STRING "Edgar Rice Burroughs";      3:STRING "";       4:STRING "";  5:INTEGER  1479296482574;    6:INTEGER  1479473591652; 7:STRING "en";    8:STRING "ru";    9:STRING "/storage/sdcard0/Файлы/Прочее/Книги/Художественные/Писатели/Edgar Rice Burroughs/Барсумская/06 The Master Mind of Mars.epub";   10:INTEGER  0;    11:STRING "0.0";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found that Cursor in android can't hold more than 1 Mb of data. That was the cause for exception.